# Is it possible to transfer "include" into module in fortran?

Tags: module, fortran, include

Assume now for some reason I can only have a file(Fortran code contained), named "inc.f90", to be used by 'include' statement in other f90 files. When I use this code in the other file, say "use.f90", I type "include 'inc.f90'". But in this case, there is path information contained in "use.f90". Then I need to organize my code files in a fixed way. For example, if I move "inc.f90" into other position("other/path/inc.f90"), I need to change the source code in "use.f90" accordingly. This is awkward! I wonder if I can use some trick to pack "inc.f90" into a module, after which I need only to tell where all files are to the compiler.

Comment: So in "use.f90", I can fix " INCLUDE 'inc.f90' " ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `gfortran`, I guess you can use the `-I` option to specify the search path for included files. For example, if we have the following `main.f90` in the current directory,

```
$ cat ./main.f90

module testmod
    implicit none
contains
    include "inc1.f90"
    include "inc2.f90"
end

program main
    use testmod
    call sub1   !! defined in inc1.f90
    call sub2   !! defined in inc2.f90
end
```

and sub1.f90 and sub2.f90 in libdir/sub1 and libdir/sub2, respectively,

```
$ ls libdir/*
libdir/sub1:
./        ../       inc1.f90

libdir/sub2:
./        ../       inc2.f90
```

with

```
$ cat libdir/sub1/inc1.f90
subroutine sub1
    print *, "hello1"
end

$ cat libdir/sub2/inc2.f90
subroutine sub2
    print *, "hello2"
end
```

we can compile them as

```
$ gfortran -Ilibdir/sub1 -Ilibdir/sub2 main.f90
```

According to `man gfortran`, there are some related options (`-idirafter` for alternative search directories and `-J` for .mod files), which may also be useful. I guess we have similar options for other compilers as well.

Comment: Great! This solved my problem. For personal interest, however, I wonder if we can have a general way to pack a piece of fragmentary code into a module?

Comment: Actually, that part is what I still cannot understand the precise goal (particularly, the meaning of "pack"). Maybe another question with more detailed intent/goal may be worth trying..? (because other people may have some idea.)

Comment: FYI, in my case, I separate various subroutines into different files, and "include" all of them into a single module (according to its computational purpose). This way, I can avoid reading a very long module file :)

Comment: Never mind. I just wondering if we can use a module to reproduce all the function of "include". Something like, I do not know, maybe we can save all the code into a string? Personally, I would like to manage all my code in module format. But it seems impossible? The goal of using 'include' is to solve the problem like this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44860277/how-to-get-a-module-with-different-type-for-code-reuse/44860671#44860671